# Why the 10-minute military alert/signal tone in the movie Arrival?

Tags: arrival

I am currently watching Arrival. I noticed that the base near the visitors have a 10-minute signal tone. A kind of alert sound.

Why is that? Does the tone force the personnel to keep concentrated/focused on the tasks? A kind of acoustic caffeine? Or to try to keep personnel awake? Or some kind of a broadcast that all units communicate their status?

Answer (score 8):

The [screenplay](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/arrival.pdf) indicates that it's the Shell that is making the tone. It appears to be warning them that their communication window (the time they can spend in the ship) is about to occur.

> **COLONEL WEBER:** *All right, all right, I get it. Stick to your list. Just—*
>
> Then: That low, bone-trembling BASS TONE **echoing out from the Shell**, rattling the equipment.

Comment: Purely for the record, in the screenplay it's a ten minute warning.

Comment: @Valorum Updated the question to 10 instead of 15 minutes warning. (...) I couldnt came across me rolleying of this 10 minute warning. 10 minutes is a peroid that came clearly out of the brain of a human, not a brain of a visitor. I could might accept that a 18-hour-interval is somehow random but the 10 minutes period ruind the movie for me. Do visitors have a base10 mathematics? Based on 10 what? 10 fingers? Nope! This ruins the whole movie for me and annoys me the whole time, duck that!

Comment: @Grim - I assume it's not precisely ten minutes. It's probably more like 10 minutes and twelve seconds but military people like to round things. Ian posits that 18 hours is just how long it takes to cycle the air but I would guess that with gravity control it could be managed in seconds (point gravity down to make air leave, reverse gravity to suck in new air) so it's more likely that it was to give the scientists time to process what they'd learned each session

Comment: @Valorum I dont think military is used who need to round up because the concept of seconds is too hard to understand. Even if they are dumb as hell and only know round numbers, even close to 10 seems such an luckystrike from 1 out of 10. Beside the luckystrike of 18 out of 24hours. You try to settle me down, but I am too authentic to accept this in my small world. Thanks anyway.